# Upper bounded wildcard, iterator and for-each loop

Tags: java, generics, casting

I don't understand why this code compiles:

```
public void test(Collection<? extends Enum> enumCollection) {
    for (Enum e : enumCollection) {
    }
}
```

and this one does not:

```
public void test(Collection<? extends Enum> enumCollection) {
    Iterator<Enum> iterator = enumCollection.iterator();
    //Required: Iterator<Java.lang.Enum>
    //Found: Iterator<capture<? extends Java.lang.Enum>>
}
```

`? extends Enum` should be a subtype of `Enum` in all cases, so why am I getting a compilation error with the iterator and why does it work with a for-each loop?

Comment: Probably for the same reason why `ArrayList<Object> foo = new ArrayList<String>();` does not work, while `Object bar = new ArrayList<String>().get(0);` is okay.

Comment: why can't you use `Collection<Enum>` instead of `Collection<? extends Enum>`

Comment: `Iterator<Enum>` means you know that `enumCollection` is of type `Enum` but  `Collection<? extends Enum> enumCollection` shows that `enumCollection` can be a subtype of `Enum` too.

Answer (score 8):

I often find that the adage *if you need to use ? in your generic you are probably doing something wrong* applies.

This works fine:

```
public <T extends Enum<T>> void test(Collection<T> enumCollection) {
    for (Enum e : enumCollection) {
    }
    Iterator<T> iterator = enumCollection.iterator();
}
```

Your problem is that you are expecting generics to act like ordinary code where an `ArrayList` is also a `List`. It is not designed for that. Generics are to ensure that you are using the **same** type, not *just some compatible type*.

In your case - to match the `? extends Enum` you could use:

```
    Iterator<?> iterator = enumCollection.iterator();
```

which works fine.

Your types do not match - and generics are there to make sure they do.

Remember that `?` does not mean *I don't care what type it is* it means *I don't want to know what type it is*. Using `?` in a generic type and then expecting to be able to make use of the type is just silly.

Comment: "This works fine" Not if you want to pass a `Collection<MyCustomEnum>` to `test`.

Comment: @tobias_k - Still works! `enum MyCustomEnum {A, B;}` and `test(Arrays.asList(MyCustomEnum.values()))` works fine.

Comment: You are right, sorry for bothering. I guess `Enum`s are special in this regard. +1

Comment: @tobias_k - This is not specific to `enum`s. In generics `X extends Y` means **exactly** that, it **must** `extend Y` a `Y` will not do. The actual type is then captured (or not if you use `?`).

Comment: I think you are wrong here. What I tried: given a `List<String>`, pass that list to a method expecting a) `List<String>` (works, obviously), b) `List<? extends String>` (also works), c) `List<? extends Object)` (works), or d) `List<Object>` (does not work), all tested with Java 8. But please correct me if I misunderstood your comment.

Comment: @tobias_k - If generics cannot determine that the classes do not match it postpones it's decision to run-time. BTW `public void test3(List<String> l) {}` `List<? extends String> l = new ArrayList<>();` `test3(l)` is not legal.

Comment: Exactly, that's what I meant with my case (d) and that's why I thought that this would not work in my first comment. However, I guess we are talking past one another here. Thanks for the insight about Enum, though.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I understand that you cannot change the generics by using the upper bound in the variable - why is that so? If I use `Iterator<? extends Enum>`, it works fine, because I only intend to access to `Enum` methods: so why can't I just declare my iterator as `<Enum>`, which should encompass all subclasses of `Enum`, and thus be the same as `? extends Enum`?

Comment: @user2572030 - Because generics are for matching types **exactly**. A `List<String>` is **not** a `List<Object>` even though `Object o = "Hello"` is valid Java.

Comment: Ah, I see now. Now if your answer could explain why the foreach loop lets you have `Enum` directly, it would be great. Florent Bayle's answer is giving some insight about it, but the JLS is making it more confusing.

Answer (score 3):

Concerning the for loop, according to the [JLS 14.14.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2), the following code:

```
public void test(Collection<? extends Enum> enumCollection) {
    for (Enum e : enumCollection) {
    }
}
```

Will be translated to something like this:

```
public <T extends Enum> void test(Collection<T> enumCollection) {
    for (Iterator<T> iterator = enumCollection.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        Enum e = (T) iterator.next();
    }
}
```

Which compiles without problem. As you can see, you will never have an `Iterator<Enum>` directly, but instead an `Iterator` of whatever you said is the type of the elements in your collection.

The relevant part of the JLS is:

> If the type of Expression is a subtype of Iterable for some type argument X, then let I be the type java.util.Iterator; otherwise, let I be the raw type java.util.Iterator.

The storage in an `Enum` variable is only done for each element, where it's relevant.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the JLS. I thought it would make it clear but it clearly says that `List<? extends Integer> l` is translated to `Iterator<Integer> #i = l.iterator()`. This is exactly my problem: the code it gets translated into does not compile. (I copied it in my IDE, removing #)